# calcCovarMatrix in multichannel image and unresolved assertion error

Tags: c++, opencv, covariance

i'm try to get covariance matrix from an image stored in cv::Mat. i need it for calculate mahalanobis distance and attempt to some color segmentation.

this is my code:

```
Mat covar, selection, meanBGR;
selection = src(roi);
calcCovarMatrix(selection, covar, meanBGR, CV_COVAR_NORMAL|CV_COVAR_ROWS);
```

the Mat src is from webcam and standard BGR opencv format, so CV_32FC3. pixels are stored (i think) in row vector order (blue, green, red).. so i think my code is correct. but i recive this runtime error:

> Assertion failed (src.channels() == 1) in mulTransposed

i tried to make a vector too in this way:

```
vector<Scalar> samples;

for(int i=0; i<selection.rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<selection.cols; j++) {

        Scalar pixel = selection.at<Scalar>(i,j);
        Scalar sample(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]);
        samples.push_back(sample);
    }
}

calcCovarMatrix(samples, covar, meanBGR, CV_COVAR_NORMAL|CV_COVAR_ROWS);
```

but i always get the same error. reading the [manual](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#calcCovarMatrix) doesn't make any kind of idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pass it a 3-channel matrix. Does this small sample work:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    Mat_<float> samples = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
                                                4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
                                                7.0, 8.0, 9.0);

    Mat cov, mu;
    cv::calcCovarMatrix(samples, cov, mu, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS);

    cout << "cov: " << endl;
    cout << cov << endl;

    cout << "mu: " << endl;
    cout << mu << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It should output:

```
cov: 
[18, 18, 18;
  18, 18, 18;
  18, 18, 18]
mu: 
[4, 5, 6]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah ok thanks for the clear example but so? how to get covariance matrix for mahalanobis distance in skin segmentation? i'm referring in the methos explained in this answer of my previous question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1634/1063

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately I think the only way to get the color co-variance is to do it manually. If you split the image and then rehape the resulting matrices into single rows, concat them back together (into a 3 row 1 channel mat) you can then just multiply by the transpose and divide by size - 1.