# Finding Variance of an image in OpenCV -Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to find the variance of a greyscale image in OpenCV -Python. I first take the image read in and split it into sub-images, I want to calculate the variance of these sub-images (`cropped_img`).

I'm not sure how to calculate variance in python, I assumed that I could calculate the covariance matrix to find the variance using the rule:

Var(X) = Cov(X,X)

The thing is I can't get my head around how to use `cv2.calcCovarMatrix()`, and I can't find any examples in python.

I did find this example in C++ but I have never used the language and im struggling to convert it into python: [calcCovarMatrix in multichannel image and unresolved assertion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795634/calccovarmatrix-in-multichannel-image-and-unresolved-assertion-error)

Here is my code:

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read in image as grey-scale
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg', 0)

#Set scale of grid 
scale = 9

#Get x and y components of image
y_len,x_len = img.shape

covar = []
for y in range(scale):
    for x in range(scale):
        #Crop image 9*9 windows
        cropped_img=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,
                          (x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]

        #Here is where I need to calc variance
        cv2.calcCovarMatrix(cropped_img, covar, meanBGR, cv2.cv.CV_COVAR_NORMAL)
        #???
        cropped_img[:] = covar

cv2.imshow('output_var',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If anyone has any ideas or if you have a better way to calculate variance then I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks.

EDIT: I also found this example in c; [mean and variance of image in single pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608782/mean-and-variance-of-image-in-single-pass), but it doesn't seem too efficient.

Comment: if you're looking for the stdev, it's a [one-liner](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.meanStdDev)

Answer (score 4):

To get the variance of gray scale image in python you can use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

var = np.var(img)
```